# For Backbone.js, how to show that Backbone.Model inherits from Backbone.Events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/, it is said that

```
every single one of the following objects inherits from Backbone.Events:

Backbone.Model
Backbone.Collection
Backbone.Router
Backbone.History
Backbone.View
```

and I can also find in `backbone.js` the following:

```
// Attach all inheritable methods to the Model prototype.
_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {  ....
```

However, I tried to check for the inheritance, by

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.__proto__ === Backbone.Events
```

in Firebug, and it shows `false`, and

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.__proto__.__proto__
```

is already `null`, meaning the end of the prototype chain.  So how can the inheritance be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you're referencing is incorrect, nothing in Backbone inherits from `Backbone.Events`. However, `Backbone.Events` is mixed into the other Backbone "classes". The bit of code you mention:

```
_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, { ...
```

is not setting up inheritance, it is simply mixing `Events` into `Model`'s prototype and the effect is similar to this:

```
for k in Events
    Model.prototype[k] = Events[k]
```

so it is simply add `Events`'s methods to `Model`. The [Backbone document](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) only says this:

> **Backbone.Events**
>
> **Events** is a module that can be mixed in to any object, giving the object the ability to bind and trigger custom named events.

Note the *mixed in* terminology.

`Backbone.Events` isn't even a constructor function (it is simply an object) so there's nothing to inherit from.

Comment: the author kindly acknowledged it is better described as a mix in and changed it in the current text.